# Can't get stripe payment Intent success metadata

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm new using stripe payments, so I decided to make it easy and implemented redirectToCheckout and stripe webhooks from the stripe documentation, I followed the steps, first I created a product from stripe's dashboard, then I added some metadata key and value, finally I wrote my code on Angular and everything was working great until I realized that i wasn't getting the expected metadata, actually it was empty.

I am using Firebase cloud functions as backend and Angular framework as front,this is my code:

**Angular**

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  lineItems: [{ price: itemSku, quantity: 1}],
  mode: 'payment',
  customerEmail: this.userEmail,
  successUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/purchase/success',
  cancelUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/purchase/failed'
})
```

**Firebase cloud function**

```
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;
    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
        response.status(404).end()
    }

    const intent = event.data.object
    switch (event.type) {
        case constants.INTENT_SUCCESS:
            // it prints the object with empty metadata
            console.log('Success object:', intent);  <- metadata:{}
            break;
        case constants.INTENT_FAILED:
            console.log('Failed:', intent.id);
            break;
    }
    response.json({received: true});
    response.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: What do you see in the stripe console? Is the webhook called?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes is getting called but the metada is `metadata:{}` at the payment intent success object, I need it with the metadata I already set up at the product dashboard

Comment: And do you see other properties of the intent object or it is totally empty?

Comment: Yes I can see the other properties of the object with values, but not with the values of this one :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each object in Stripe will have different metadata. It sounds like metadata was added to the `Product`  object which will not be copied to the `PaymentIntent`.

I would listen for the `checkout.session.completed` webhook notification event type, then fetch the Checkout Session and [expanding](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) it's related `line_items`, `price`, and `product`.

```
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
    "cs_test_xxx", {
      expand: ["line_items.data.price.product"]
    }
  )
  console.log(res.line_items.data[0].price.product);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! I'm going to try it and I'll tell you ;)

Comment: I have a question, where should I do this ? outside the webhook call ? I'm sorry I'm new at this

Comment: I'd add another constant, and add a line to your webhook switch:

 switch (event.type) {   
    case constants.CHECKOUT_SUCCESS:    
      const session...

Comment: It is intuitive to me that Stripe would not copy metadata from the `Product` to the `PaymentIntent` since there could be all sorts of irregular many-to-many relationships between these two objects. However, highly unintuitively to me, if you pass the metadata to the `checkout.session` object, it still doesn't get passed to the `PaymentIntent` object, even though there is a 1-to-1 relationship between completed sessions and completed payments. This is not currently mentioned in Stripe's documentation. Your solution, listening to the `checkout.session.completed event`, seems to work for me.

Comment: @cazort, you can technically create a Checkout Session with metadata attached directly to the session at the top level and _also_ attached to the payment intent if you pass the `payment_intent_data.metadata` parameter. https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata